# Action Filters on Controller, but only used if another ([HttpPost]) is applied to method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I'd like to apply a filter at the Controller level, but only have it's logic apply to action-methods that have the [HttpPost] filter on them directly.

Perhaps it is possible to detect from within one filter whether another filter has been applied on the current action method?

Or is there another way of achieving the effect I outlined in my first sentence? Perhaps there is a way of extending or replacing the HttpFilter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
public class PostActiongFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public virtual void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
        var actionParams = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters
        var actionParamsTypes = actionParams.Cast<ParameterDescriptor>()
                                      .Select(x => x.ParameterType).ToArray();
        var controllerType = filterContext.Controller.GetType();            
        var actionMethodInfo = controllerType.GetMethod(actionName,
                                                        actionParamsTypes, null);            
        var isMethodPost = actionMethodInfo.IsDefiend(typeof(HttpPostAttribute),
                                                      false);

        if (!isMethodPost)
            return;

        // Do what you want for post here...                         
    }
}
```

Comment: Correction in your last line:  var isMethodPost = actionMethodInfo.IsDefined(typeof(HttpPostAttribute), false);

Comment: @Ryk, thanks. BTW, this site allows you to edit\suggest an edit when you want. thanks anyway, you were spot on.

Answer (score -1):

Well, HttpPostAttribute is sealed. But you can peek into it (ILSpy is your friend) for inspiration :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class HttpPostAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    private static readonly AcceptVerbsAttribute _innerAttribute = new AcceptVerbsAttribute(HttpVerbs.Post);
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return HttpPostAttribute._innerAttribute.IsValidForRequest(controllerContext, methodInfo);
    }
}
```

pretty simple huh ? You just create exactly the same logic, and in return put

```
return (yourCustomCondition) && HttpPostAttribute._innerAttribute.IsValidForRequest(controllerContext, methodInfo);
```

Comment: This answer is not really a general solution since the internal logic of the HttpPost attribute may be changed in a higher version of MVC and then this solution will stop working. Answer provided by @gdoron is much better in this case.